# Function value is undefined when called within click function conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is an extension of question ‘[jQuery output to console sum of 2 variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920322/jquery-output-to-console-sum-of-2-variables)’.

I have the following function:

```
function printSum() {
    console.log('Sum:' + (c.getBehaviour() + t.getBehaviour()));
}
```

and wish to load HTML dependant upon `printSum()` value within a click function like so:

```
$('#surname-help-label').click(function(e) {
    var helpText = $('#surname-help-text').html('loading&hellip;');

    if (printSum() >= 25) {
        helpText.load('help-text.html div:nth-of-type(2)');
    } else {
        helpText.load('help-text.html div:first');
        console.log('what do you get:' + printSum());
    };

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I have added in the line `console.log('what do you get:' + printSum());` for debug purposes and the value it returns is `undefined` which means the `else {}` block is always called. How do I remedy this?

[Full code jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pf2PQ/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not retuning anything. If you don't make your function return what you want it to return, then it won't return what you want it to return.

To make it return want you want it to return, you need to make it return what you want it to return so that it'll return what you want it to return and you'll be able to use what it returned.

```
function printSum() {
    console.log('Sum:' + (c.getBehaviour() + t.getBehaviour()));
    return c.getBehaviour() + t.getBehaviour();
}
```

[MDN `return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: You sir, are a cunning linguist ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything in printsum function.
Just write after console.log inside printsum function
return c.getbehaviour() + t.getbehaviour();